# WebBrowser Unable to show content in windows phone 7 Emulator ?

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I am using `WebBrowser` control in a page. While running the app in the emulator, the control is showing a progress bar which always end showing empty page. Is there a problem with proxy setting or do I need to set something else?

Comment: Try the default Internet Explorer in the emulator. If the same thing happens, then you have a problem with your internet connection settings.

Comment: Do you use an URL or a local page or a string to display the content ?

Comment: I tried both URL and a string but nothing is working for me.Even if i search a keyword in wp7 emulator,i get list of links but when i click any link it gives me an empty page eventually...

Comment: Do i need GPU  for Showing WebBrowser content in WP7 emulator?Like for xna its required.Whenever am trying to search a keyword in emulator IE ,its showing matched lists but upon click on any link ,eventually i am getting blank white page always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that your system has proper graphics card. Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks.I got the answer.I had old graphics card with WDDM 1.0,but we need WDDM 1.1 for WP SDK 7.1.